# How do I generate all possible combinations of a 3 x 2 matrix?

Tags: java, matrix

I'm stuck trying to create a 3 x 2 matrix that only contains 0 and 1 and prints out all the possible combinations, BUT it can only contain one 1 and one 0 for each row, the numbers have nothing to do with each other than that they are unique, much like a betting table for say tennis or something:

```
0 1       1 0       0 1       0 1      0 1
0 1       1 0       0 1       1 0      1 0
0 1       1 0       1 0       1 0      0 1
```

Here's the code:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = {{0,1}};

        System.out.println("Array:");

        for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++){
                System.out.print(array[row][column] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I got right know. I don't know where to take it from here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're going to need a few more information to effectively help you. Please show us some code that you have already written in attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have any other input to help me with the problem? =)

Answer (score 1):

For a general case of an N-by-2 matrix there will be 2^N combinations that meet your criteria.  Consider that each row can only be in two states: `[0, 1]`, or `[1, 0]`.

Start with a matrix where every row is in the initial state `[0, 1]`.  Then, for every number X where 0 <= X < 2^N, convert X to binary.  When the `M`th bit is 1, reverse the `M`th row's values.

For example, binary 000 would correspond to:

```
0 1
0 1
0 1
```

While binary 101 would correspond to:

```
1 0 (swapped)
0 1
1 0 (swapped)
```

Comment: Thx! I shall see if I can solve it, still new to programming.

Comment: Nope, im completely stuck, i got nothing

Comment: Could you help me further with this? Im stuck